# Different join method() behaviour with console log and return keyword

Tags: javascript

Please may I ask why the `console.log(title.join("-"));` never seems to be logged?

Surely the output should be 4 separate logs of the output for each method call that ends with `join()`

We never seem to see the `join()` when logging it, where I would expect the output to be 'winter-is-coming'

However when the `return` keyword is used we do get the output "winter-is-coming" - why is this difference occuring between `console.log` and `return`

```
const globalTitle = "Winter Is Coming";

function urlSlug(title) {

    console.log(title.toLowerCase());
    console.log(title.trim());
    console.log(title.split(/\s+/));
    console.log(title.join("-")); // Expected output: "winter-is-coming"

    return title
        .toLowerCase()
        .trim()
        .split(/\s+/)   
        .join("-");
}

const winterComing = urlSlug(globalTitle); // Expected output: "winter-is-coming"
console.log(winterComing);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`title.split(/\s+/)` returns an array, it does not mutate the string to an array. This is why you cannot call join() on it. A string object does not have a join method.

```js
const globalTitle = "Winter Is Coming";

function urlSlug(title) {

    console.log(title.toLowerCase());
    console.log(title.trim());
    console.log(title.split(/\s+/));
    // title.split(/\s+/) returns an array, it does not mutate the string to an array
    console.log( typeof title )
    // this is why you cannot call join() on it. A string object does not have a join method 
    
    //console.log(title.join("-")); // Expected output: "winter-is-coming"

    return title
        .toLowerCase()
        .trim()
        .split(/\s+/)   
        .join("-");
}

const winterComing = urlSlug(globalTitle); // Expected output: "winter-is-coming"
console.log(winterComing);
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings in JavaScript are immutable. As you can see below calling `title.split()` does nothing to the value referenced by `title`:

```js
const title = "a b c"
title.split(/\s+/)
console.log("title is a", typeof title, "and has the value:", title)
```

Hence each successive console log in the `urlSlug` function is always acting on the original value of `title`, i.e. the string `"Winter Is Coming"`.

If you run your code without the logging, you will see it produces the desired result:

```js
const globalTitle = "Winter Is Coming";

function urlSlug(title) {
    return title
        .toLowerCase()
        .trim()
        .split(/\s+/)   
        .join("-");
}

const winterComing = urlSlug(globalTitle); // Expected output: "winter-is-coming"
console.log(winterComing);
```

This is because you are *chaining* calls on `title`, each call acting on the result of the last. Then you are returning the result of the last call.

Answer (score 0):

Strings do not have a .join method, so title.join(...) is nonsense. When you do the .split() you turn a string into an array, which does have a .join() method